# Docker python output csv file

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a script python which should output a file csv. I'm trying to have this file in the current working directory but without success.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip

WORKDIR /opt/oracle 
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient- 
basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \ unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm 
-f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \ cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* 
&& rm -f jdbc occi mysql *README jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \ echo 
/opt/oracle/instantclient > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && 
ldconfig 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY . /app 
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install pystan 
RUN apt-get -y update && python3 -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "Main.py" ]
```

And run the container with the following command

```
docker container run -v $pwd:/home/learn/rstudio_script/output image
```

Comment: Perhaps Main.py isn't outputting to /home/learn/rstudio_script/output.

Comment: If the main goal of your process is to read and write local files, Docker’s filesystem isolation is actively working against you.  Consider running the same process outside Docker in a Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad practice to bind a volume just to have 1 file on your container be saved onto your host.

Instead, what you should leverage is the copy command:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

You can set this command to auto execute with bash, after your docker run.

So something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this stores the container id
CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -dit img)

docker cp $CONTAINER_ID:/some_path host_path
```

If you are adamant on using a bind volume, then as the others have pointed out, the issue is most likely your python script isn't outputting the csv to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Your script `Main.py` is probably not trying to write to `/home/learn/rstudio_script/output`. The working directory in the container is `/app` because of the last `WORKDIR` directive in the Dockerfile. You can override that at runtime with `--workdir` but then the `CMD` would have to be changed as well.

One solution is to have your script write files to `/output/` and then run it like this:

```
docker container run -v $PWD:/output/ image
```